# differences between virtual and real architecture of cuda

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Trying to understand the differences between virtual and real architecture of cuda, and how the different configurations will affect the performance of the program, e.g.

```
-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21
-gencode arch=compute_21,code=sm_21
...
```

The following explanation was given in NVCC manual,

> GPU compilation is performed via an intermediate representation, PTX
>   ([...]), which can
>       be considered as assembly for a virtual GPU architecture. Contrary to an actual graphics
>       processor, such a virtual GPU is defined entirely by the set of capabilities, or features,
>       that it provides to the application. In particular, a virtual GPU architecture provides a
>       (largely) generic instruction set, and binary instruction encoding is a non-issue because
>       PTX programs are always represented in text format.
>       Hence, a nvcc compilation command always uses two architectures: a compute
>       architecture to specify the virtual intermediate architecture, plus a real GPU architecture
>       to specify the intended processor to execute on. For such an nvcc command to be valid,
>       the real architecture must be an implementation (someway or another) of the virtual
>       architecture. This is further explained below.
>       The chosen virtual architecture is more of a statement on the GPU capabilities that
>       the application requires: using a smallest virtual architecture still allows a widest range
>       of actual architectures for the second nvcc stage. Conversely, specifying a virtual
>       architecture that provides features unused by the application unnecessarily restricts the
>       set of possible GPUs that can be specified in the second nvcc stage.

But still don't quite get how the performance will be affected by different configurations (or, maybe only affect the selection of the physical GPU devices?). In particular, this statement is most confusing to me:

> In particular, a virtual GPU architecture provides a
>       (largely) generic instruction set, and binary instruction encoding is a non-issue because
>       PTX programs are always represented in text format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [NVIDIA CUDA Compiler Driver NVCC](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) User Guide Section on [GPU Compilation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#gpu-compilation) provides a very thorough description of virtual and physical architecture and how the concepts are used in the build process.

The virtual architecture specifies the feature set that is targeted by the code. The table listed below shows some of the evolution of the virtual architecture. When compiling you should specify the lowest virtual architecture that has a sufficient feature set to enable the program to be executed on the widest range of physical architectures.

Virtual Architecture Feature List (from the User Guide)

```
compute_10   Basic features
compute_11   + atomic memory operations on global memory
compute_12   + atomic memory operations on shared memory
             + vote instructions
compute_13   + double precision floating point support
compute_20   + Fermi support
compute_30   + Kepler support
```

The physical architecture specifies the implementation of the GPU. This provides the compiler with the instruction set, instruction latency, instruction throughput, resource sizes, etc. so that the compiler can optimally translate the virtual architecture to binary code.

It is possible to specify multiple virtual and physical architecture pairs to the compiler and have the compiler back the final PTX and binary into a single binary. At runtime the CUDA driver will choose the best representation for the physical device that is installed. If binary code is not provided in the *fatbinary* file the driver can use the JIT runtime for the best PTX implementation.

Comment: Just for people wondering: the term NVIDIA uses in their documentation now is "real architecture" rather than "physical architecture".

Answer (score 3):

"Virtual architecture" code will get compiled by a just-in-time compiler before being loaded on the device. AFAIK, it is the same compiler as the one NVCC invokes when building "physical architecture" code offline - so I don't know if there will be any differences in the resulting application performance.

Basically, every generation of the CUDA hardware is binary incompatible with previous generation - imagine next generation of Intel processors sporting ARM instruction set. This way, virtual architectures provide an intermediate representation of the CUDA application that can be compiled for compatible hardware. Every hardware generation introduces new features (e.g. atomics, CUDA Dynamic Parallelism) that require new instructions - that's why you need new virtual architectures.

Basically, if you want to use CDP you should compile for SM 3.5. You can compile it to device binary that will have assembly code for specific CUDA device generation or you can compile it to PTX code that can be compiled into device assembly for any device generation that provides these features.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual architecture specifies what capabilities a GPU has and the real architecture specifies how it does it.

I can't think of any specific examples off hand. A (probably not correct) example may be a virtual GPU specifying the number of cores a card has, so code is generated targeting that number of cores, whereas the real card may have a few more for redundancy (or a few less due to manufacturing errors) and some methods of mapping to the cores that are actually in use, which can be placed on top of the more generic code generated in the first step.

You can think of the PTX code sort of like assembly code, which targets a certain architecture, which can then be compiled to machine code for a specific processor. Targeting the assembly code for the right kind of processor will, in general, generate better machine code.

Answer (score -1):

well usually what nvidia writes as document causes people (including myself) to become more confused! (just me maybe!)

you are concerned with the performance, basically what this says is that don't be (probably) but you should.basically the GPU architecture is like nature. they run something on it and something happens. then they try to explain it. and then they feed it to you.

at the end should probably run some tests and see what configuration gives the best result.

the virtual architecture is what is designed to let you think freely. you should obey that, use as much as threads as you want, you can assign virtually everything as number of threads and blocks, doesn't matter, it will be translated to PTX and the device will run it.

the only problem is, if you assign more than 1024 threads per a single block you will get 0 s as the result, because the device(the real architecture) doesn't support it.

or for example your device support the CUDA 1.2, you can define double pointing variables in your code, but again you will get 0 s as the result because simply the device can't run it.

performance wise you have to know that every 32 thread (e.g. warps) have to access a single position in memory or else your access will be serialized and so on.

So I hope you've got the point by now, It is a relatively new science and GPU is a really sophisticated piece of hardware architecture, everybody is trying to make the best of it but it's a game of testing and a little knowledge of actual architecture behind CUDA. I suggest that search for GPU architecture and see how the virtual threads and thread blocks are actually implemented.